# C# LINQ Xml query confusion

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Given the following xml:

```
    <Location>
        <LocationAttribute>
            <OptionType>
                <Code>02</Code>
                <Description>RetailLocation</Description>
            </OptionType>
            <OptionCode>
                <Code>03</Code>
                <Description>Drop Box</Description>
            </OptionCode>
        </LocationAttribute>

        <LocationAttribute>
            <OptionType>
                <Code>03</Code>
                <Description>AdditionalServices</Description>
            </OptionType>
            <OptionCode>
                <Category>06</Category>
                <Code>031</Code>
                <Name>**Find a drop off location**</Name>
            </OptionCode>
            <OptionCode>
                <Category>07</Category>
                <Code>001</Code>
                <Name>**Ground**</Name>                 
            </OptionCode>
            <OptionCode>
                <Category>07</Category>
                <Code>002</Code>
                <Name>**Air**</Name>
            </OptionCode>
        </LocationAttribute>
    </Location>
```

How can I parse out the value of the Name attribute for each option code, when the OptionType's code is 3? I have been trying something like:

```
List<string> services = item.Descendants("LocationAttribute")
                .Where(service => service.Element("OptionType").Value == "3")
                .Select(service => service.Element("OptionCode").Element("Description").Value).ToList()
```

Comment: As an aside, you say you want the value of the `Name` *attribute*: there are no attributes in this XML -  `Name` is an *element*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do a `SelectMany`. And inside `Select` the `Value` of the Name `Element` for each of the OptionCode `Elements`.  Also you have to check the `Value` of the Code `Element` of the OptionType `Element` and since it is a `string` comparison you have to include the leading "0".

```
var services = item.Descendants("LocationAttribute")
    .Where(loc => loc.Element("OptionType").Element("Code").Value == "03")
    .SelectMany(loc => loc.Elements("OptionCode")
                          .Select(code => code.Element("Name").Value));
```